# how to make UIView with equal width and height with SnapKit in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, snapkit

I want to make a UIView rectangular with SnapKit in Swift, like this

```
lazy var customView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect())
        self.addSubview(view)
        view.snp.makeConstraints({ (make) in
            make.left.top.bottom.equalToSuperview().inset(self.inset)
            make.width.equalTo(make.height)  // Error in this line
        })
        return view
    }()
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have to use `view.snp.height` instead of `make.height`:

```
lazy var customView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect())
    self.addSubview(view)
    view.snp.makeConstraints({ (make) in
        make.left.top.bottom.equalToSuperview().inset(self.inset)
        make.width.equalTo(view.snp.height) // <---
    })
    return view
}()
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have 2 view on same superview, you can do next:

```
    view1.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.leading.equalToSuperview()
        make.bottom.equalToSuperview()
        make.top.equalToSuperview()
    }

    view2.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.trailing.equalToSuperview()
        make.bottom.equalToSuperview()
        make.top.equalToSuperview()
        make.leading.equalTo(view1.snp.trailing)
        make.width.equalTo(view1.snp.width)
    }
```

and result

[image]

In same manner, using `view.snp.width` or `view.snp.height` you can setup equality of views using **SnapKit**

Answer (score -1):

```
    view.snp.makeConstraints({ (make) in
        make.left.top.bottom.equalToSuperview().inset(self.inset)
        make.width.equalTo(view.snp.height) 
    })
```

Comment: Please add some explanations